# Embed inner HTML into SVG, and center align

Tags: html, css, svg

Sorry if I'm not going about this the right way. I am trying to embed HTML within an SVG shape, and trying to center align the HTML with the shape.

Here is my code:

```
<svg xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="shape1" width="200" height="200" style="margin-top:-100px;">
                            <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="100"  fill="white">


                            </circle>
                            <foreignObject x="0" y="80" width="100%" height="100%">
                                <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                                    <div>
                                     <h3 style="font-family:'myriad Pro' ">HOME</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </body>
                             </foreignObject>

                        </svg>
```

As it stands, I have to do it manually, but it does not seem to be consistent across Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: seems to work ? http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/N6HBQ/

Comment: What, specifically, is inconsistent?